# What's a good (free) client for MySQL on Windows?

Tags: mysql, client

I am almost repeating a question done here by another user, but related to MySQL. What do you think is the best free (if any) MySQL client software?

Thank you!

Comment: Software clients are constantly released and updated according to what's common on the market. The best place to learn these things would be in the [Stack Exchange Third Place](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) (our chat system) and to ask people what they are currently using. We are trying to track down these "rather soft questions" and close them, so feel free to point me to "almost repeating another question here" so I can also close them. To answer your question, however, what do you need in a client?

Comment: Thanks, my only concern with these (great) Stack Exchange forums is the enormous amount of different forums. It certainly puzzles other users as it puzzles me. Where to go? Some topics overlap. Since this is a database forum, I thought it would be the right place, but my question probably overlaps with a forum about applications. Similar to this, I found "What's a good (free) client for Oracle 8 on Linux / Ubuntu?" Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the similar topic. The problem with the SE Engine has been noted and debated amongst the directorial users many times over on [metase] and I assure you, we're not immune to understanding the problem you're mentioning. However, the problem with your question inherently becomes "it depends". Because you've given no good description of what you need. Do you need a Windows client? A web client? Does the mysql command line interface not work? Do you need a GUI?

Comment: [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) has a free [Express edition](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows) on Stackoverflow, you will have some idea.

I use the client provide by [Mysql itself](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html), it's maybe not the best, but I can get my job done with it

Comment: The question link is dead and the Workbench is bloated. I use the unstable but excellent [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).

Comment: Sadly HeidiSQL works very poorly on 64bit Windows 10 (crashes a lot, no auto recovery of lost querys) so teh search goes on.